# Setting up a git server

Tags: server, git

I've recently set up ubuntu-server on Amazon EC2. I would like to use it as my git server, so I could store my repos there.

So, where can I find some detailed instructions of how to setup git on ubuntu server? All these SSH keys and stuff like that, multiple users, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is an Ubuntu-related question (beyond the obvious "it's linux"), also have you even looked at the [git documentation](http://book.git-scm.com/index.html)? There's mentions there of setting up a [public](http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html) as well as a [private](http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_private_repository.html) repository.

Comment: @BonboBingo Saying "Just search Google" really isn't a solution. The majority of questions here could be answered with "if you search long enough..." Ask Ubuntu aims to be *the* authority Question and Answer site providing 1st level answers instead of a wall of answers that say "Just Google" - for more information check the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: There is a useful step guide here: help.ubuntu.com/community/Git.    
 
@Marco Ceppi Sorry but I wasn't polemical. And then the link that I had posted seems to be quite relevant to question ... Okay now as an answer?

Comment: @BonboBingo comments don't count as answers! I was merely commenting on the "Search Google" portion of your comment. If you wanted to answer with details about the Git article in the Ubuntu Help guide you should use the "Your Answer" box at the bottom of this page! :)

Comment: "instead of a wall of answers that say "Just Google" - for more information check the"...
ok you're right :) Let's stop here.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Comment: You can see, that there are many ways to setup an git server. Maybe you should *ask a little different* so there is a way to summon some git servers with pros/cons

Comment: I [wrote an answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/518296/creating-a-repo-with-git-or-any-version-control/518300#518300) for this very question. Follow the Microserver method and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi When someone says "just google", flag it as not constructive.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [tutorial to install a Git server as aking1012 proposed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12647/setting-up-a-git-server/12658#12658) you or you could just install SSH server on your EC2 instance (probably it would be wise to secure it and change the default port).

Git can be server-less you init your repository and then you access it from remote via SSH. So instructions like this on the Ubuntu Server should do it:

```
GIT_DIR=project.git git init  
cd project.git  
git --bare update-server-info  
cp hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
```

Finally install SSH on your server:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh-server
```

Now, you should configure SSH to secure it.

It's time to put your project online (the data you already have on your development machine):

```
git push ssh://<username>@<remote-git-hostname>/path/to/project.git master
```

And now you can start cloning around. You go on your development machine:

```
git clone ssh://<username>@<remote-git-hostname>/path/to/dir.git
```

Check this [excellent resource on Git](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch06.html#_git_over_ssh_http).

And for generating your ssh keys for safer authentication, you can read this article about [SSH authentication](http://www.berthon.eu/wiki/foss:wikishelf:ssh:authentication).

Comment: Shouldn't thatbe `openssh-server`?

Comment: i like this simpler approach of just using pre-shared ssh keys, but when they ask for "setting up a git server" i think they want multi-user permissions and the like

Comment: @jorge it seems that `ssh-server` is an alias to openssh-server, at least on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @aking1012 yes, my answer is just complementary to yours. Now they have 2 options, one easy to set-up using SSH, but then SSH does the 'user management', another where you can set-up a git server and have better control over user management. Both answers are interesting and together more complete :)

Comment: well, this could work, but logging via SSH to Amazon EC2 machines requires public/private keypair (ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@address). Also, I have to remember the path (ubuntu@address:/var/www/dir1/dir2), instead of just git clone git.mydomain.com/repository

Comment: @Pawel good point. That's why some people put the git repository at the file system root. But yes, you need ssh keys or accounts. Or you could use HTTP, but then you don't have really nice access control AFAIK.

Comment: @PawełKarpiński - You can set up a client-side SSH config file in `~/.ssh/config` to handle the username/host address, key input, ports, and whatnot.

Comment: Is there any free control-panel-like application for a git server? I mean one that shows basic information about the respositories on my server (commits, commit times, diff-views etc.)

Comment: @Victor you might want to look at GitLab, but it's much more complex to install or maintain.

Answer (score 15):

For all my Git server setups I use [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) which allows for a security granularity of "per-branch" access. Setup is pretty straight forward if you're doing it on a remote server it's as easy as running an interactive script. In addition to this "easy-to-setup" nature it also has a package in Natty and Maverick

```
sudo apt-get install gitolite
```

This won't provide a web frontend like Github, or Gitweb - but you can easily configure and install those on top of something like Gitolite.

Answer (score 9):

I like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki/). The Pro Git book has a [section](http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html) on it but I recommend reading the whole book.

As for your multiple users requirement:

> Gitolite allows you to specify
>   permissions not just by repository
>   (like Gitosis does), but also by
>   branch or tag names within each
>   repository. That is, you can specify
>   that certain people (or groups of
>   people) can only push certain “refs”
>   (branches or tags) but not others.

Answer (score 7):

http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way can be slightly modified to suit your purposes...a similar tutorial http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=277.

Comment: note: I am currently putting together a 0 to done rvm,ree/ruby,rails,git tutorial for development client and development server tutorial.  it just draws a lot of online tutorials into one place and modifies them a bit, but it's still a work in progress at the moment.

Comment: these tutorials are awesome, but well, they're pretty much complicated. Aren't there any "shorter" tutorials? :)

Comment: I haven't seen anything more straightforward...most of the tutorials for gitorious and gitosis don't go through creating a sample project and testing(something I think should be in every tutorial).  If I see another tut that's more direct I'll keep this thread in mind

Comment: @PawełKarpiński - What's so complicated about them? I've used the Gitosis setup before, and it's actually very easy.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely follow the official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git (section **Setting up Git and Project Management**)

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked the best for me, was setting up WebDAV.

- `sudo a2enmod sudo dav_fs`
- `sudo a2enmod dav`
- add new file to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and name it, for example, `git.yourserver.com`. Edit it and add following lines:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/git.yourserver.com/repos
ServerName git.yourserver.net
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

<Location />
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "git repos"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/git.yourserver.net/password.dav
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

`</VirtualHost>`

- create directory `/var/www/git.yourserver.com` and directory `repos` inside id
- `sudo chown www-data /var/www/git.yourserver.com/repos`
- `sudo htpasswd -c /var/www/git.yourserver.com/password.dav user_login` and enter password for user named `user_login`
- `sudo chown root:www-data /var/www/git.yourserver.com/password.dav`
- `sudo chmod 640 /var/www/git.yourserver.com/password.dav`

Now, `sudo a2ensite git.yourserver.com` and `sudo service apache2 restart`.

- Enter `/var/www/git.yourserver.com/repos` and create directory, for example, `myrepo.git`
- `cd myrepo.git`
- `git --bare init`
- `git update-server-info`

Now, logout from your remote server and go to local directory you want to edit your files in.

```
git clone http://user_login:user_password@git.yourserver.com/myrepo.git
```

and you've finished. If you want to send your commited changes to the server:

```
git push origin master
```

You can create as many users as you want using `sudo htpasswd`. Just remember not to use `-c` switch, when adding more users, because old file will be deleted.

Comment: HTTP is the "dumb" protocol that is supported but strongly discouraged.  The native git protocol works much better, and is easier to set up since all you have to do is have a working ssh server ( which you already should ) and install git-core.  No need to muck about with apache at all.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to achieve with [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki/). In less than an hour you will have easy configurable and secure multiuser git server.

I have an howto article on [my site](http://realcnbs.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I also like the **gitolite** approach for managing users and security.  I have a Git + gitolite server AMI for EC2 currently being tested.  Feel free to give it a try; documentation is available here:

> [**Alestic Git Server**](http://alestic.com/alestic-git/)

Using this approach, you can have a central Git server with private repositories running in a matter of minutes.  There is a learning curve for gitolite and EC2 if you aren't familiar with them.