# migrate git repositories

Tags: server, git

I have an old laptop `IBM Z61t` as my git server.  I want to upgrade my laptop server to a desktop server(the laptop server will not use anymore).

how could I setup and migrate the git repositories to my desktop server without losing histories. It's quiet different from [setting up a git server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12647/setting-up-a-git-server).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply copy the directory with the normal filesystem tools, or run a `git clone` on the new machine to copy, since you seem to already have the exiting machine set up as a server.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to setup a git server, simply [do a **`bundle`** of your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309) on your old laptop.

```
cd  /repos/git/job.git
git bundle create /repos/git/job.bundle --all
```

That will generate *one* file `job.bundle`, that you can copy (through any mean you want: USB key, ...) onto your other server.

Once copied, you can clone from that bundle (which acts as a git repo):

```
git clone --bare job.bundle  /repos/git/public.git
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I want to setup a new git server without losing the histories.

Answer (score 0):

[for my own reference, just push to origin:`git push origin master` *囧* ]

**first**: initialize new repository at desktop server

```
mkdir /repos/git/job.git
GIT_DIR=/repos/git/job.git git init
```

**second**: clone the repository

```
git clone ssh://laptopserver.com/repos/git/job.git
```

**third**: config and push to new repository

```
cd /directory/job
git config -e
```

change the *url* from *laptopserver.com* to *desktopserver.com*

```
git push origin master
```