# Creating a repo with git( or any version control)

Tags: backup, repository, git

I have all my code/projects as repos in github. I use git a lot, I do have few projects which I cannot push to github at the same time, I want to keep a backup on my External Hard drive, is there any existing software where you can turn your external harddrive into a repo where I can just  git push  and the code gets pushed to the repo on my harddrive?

This makes it really easy to push when you are working and keep a backup.

Simple put, Git hub locally on a harddrive. Thats it.

If it does not exist, how to get started on this and write my own software ? Give your insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## GitHub Micro-Server Method

---

To do this, you will need a public key. Info on generating one can be found all over the internet. Do that now. You'll need it in a sec. You will also need the `openssh-server` package installed.

First off, you need to prepare the environment for Git. To do this, you need to make a user.

```
sudo adduser git
su git
cd
mkdir .ssh
```

This user will do all of the Git functions. You're gonna need your public key here. Simply run:

```
cat /path/to/your/public/key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod -R go= ~/.ssh
```

Now, you have SSH and the Git user completely set up. Now, we need to make a Git project. To do this, run these commands (still as Git user):

```
cd ~ 
mkdir git
cd git 
mkdir project.git 
cd project.git 
git --bare init
```

**You must shell in and do the above commands everytime you want to make a new repo. More details later. I promise!**

Now you have a working Git server you can connect to! You can do all the fun stuff you like doing with Git now!

```
cd myproject
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin git@localhost:/home/git/git/project.git
git push origin master
```

You can of course invite other people on your local network to use this Git server, as long as they connect with your local IP instead of `localhost`.

Now, one project is most likely not enough for you. Fortunately there's a simple way to add/remove repos. Run the following commands:

```
su git
cd ~/git
mkdir project_name.git
cd project_name.git
git --bare init
```

Then, just connect to the other Git repo when you need to. It's all just changing variables!

You can also (if you want) have a web interface to Git. Info is available from the [GitHub official source.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb)

Source for this guide: [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) -- It is a great place for learning how to start a Git server. Start from 4.4 (linked) and move onwards.

## `file:///` URI Method

---

Feh. As @muru pointed out in a comment, Git supports the `file:///` URI. Here is a way to do it with no users, but no more micro-server in case your friends come over to play.

As you:

```
cd ~ 
mkdir .git-projects
cd .git-projects
mkdir project.git 
cd project.git 
git --bare init
```

To connect:

```
cd myproject
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin file:///home/user/.git-project/project.git
git push origin master
```

I personally like the microserver better. You can move it easier, esp. if you get a VPS.

### Final Comments

---

The SSH server method does not allow you to save to an external hard drive (easily), but the `file:///` method does. Just change the paths!

You could, theoretically, make the "git" user's home on the external hard drive, but that might cause more troubles than good.

Comment: You don't need to use ssh to localhost. Git supports the file:// protocol (in fact, you can skip the protocol and just specify the path).

Comment: @muru Feh. It's 2AM here, and this allows you to host it as a servlet if need be. More customizable. ***-Edited-***

Comment: @muru Better now?

Comment: Indeed. One can set up the SSH+user things any time, since the bare repo works no matter how you access it. So setting up all this until the friends actually do come to play is over-engineering. +1, now.